# How to make two left navbars with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar

I am trying to make a simple design including two left columns each including a navbar and one right column with the content.
I have tried a lot of things but each time I have a problem :

- my columns don't stay on the left of my page (I want the two columns left fixed size, and the content column fluid taking the rest of the
  page)
- my columns overlap
- the content overlaps with the content

I can't figure out what is wrong. This is what I desire to obtain :

[image]

And this is a sample of my actual code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND  </a>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tralalala1<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">RSubMenue</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">BSubMenut</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SSubMenu</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tralalala1<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">SubsubMenu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubSubMenut</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubSub Menu4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubSub Menu5</a></li>

        </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
      <div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <img id="TimeLine" src="http://img.playbuzz.com/image/upload/f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/cdn/a123d728-dd6e-46b1-85c2-5907d9fbb488/5b3da9cf-d8b7-41cd-ae02-a414dbde71fc.jpg" orgwidth="1008" orgheight="709" usemap="#image-maps-2017-11-27-071035" alt="TimeLine Demande de Ticketing Generale"
            align="centre" border="0" height="709" width="1008">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed some of the tags up which weren't closed correctly.

- You don't need so many container-elements. You can have one as your outermost element.
- Are you using offset on purpose? Have a look which column classes I used.
- Second navbar wasn't closed correctly

I tried to keep the example simple. Click „Run code snipped” and try full page to see the result.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
 
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-2">

      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND  </a>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tralalala1<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>  
              <li><a href="#">RSubMenue</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">BSubMenut</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SSubMenu</a></li>     
            </ul>
           </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

       <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tralalala1<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">SubsubMenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSubMenut</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSub Menu4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSub Menu5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
      Content
      <img id="TimeLine" src="http://img.playbuzz.com/image/upload/f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/cdn/a123d728-dd6e-46b1-85c2-5907d9fbb488/5b3da9cf-d8b7-41cd-ae02-a414dbde71fc.jpg" orgwidth="1008" orgheight="709" usemap="#image-maps-2017-11-27-071035" alt="TimeLine Demande de Ticketing Generale" align="centre" border="0" height="709" width="1008">
    </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was using offset because my columns where overlapping somehow and couldn't find why. Also, I don't understand why "Brand" is left of my menu items instead of under ? Anyway thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[**OFFICIAL BOOTSTRAP GRID DOCUMENTATION**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)- Please go through this documentation to get better idea how to use the following classes.

- `container`/`container-fluid`
- `row`
- `col-sm`/`col-md`/`col-lg`....and others

You don't necessarily need to use the offset in your case, as they all are in the same row.

Better to use all of them in same class i.e. `row`

---

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND  </a>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tralalala1<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">RSubMenue</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">BSubMenut</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SSubMenu</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tralalala1<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">SubsubMenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSubMenut</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSub Menu4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubSub Menu5</a></li>

          </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <img id="TimeLine" src="http://img.playbuzz.com/image/upload/f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/cdn/a123d728-dd6e-46b1-85c2-5907d9fbb488/5b3da9cf-d8b7-41cd-ae02-a414dbde71fc.jpg" orgwidth="1008" orgheight="709" usemap="#image-maps-2017-11-27-071035" alt="TimeLine Demande de Ticketing Generale"
            align="centre" border="0" height="709" width="1008">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```